# regex to use lowercase modifier

Tags: php, regex, lowercase

I have this code, but is there any way of converting to so that the value of `$2` is lowercase by default, from a multi-case input

```
$m = '|([\w\d]*)\s?(https?://([\d\w\.-]+\.[\w\.]{2,6})[^\s\]\[\<\>]*/?)|i';
$r = '$1 <a href="$2" title="Go To $2" target="_blank" style="text-decoration:none;">$2</a>';
$content = preg_replace($m,$r,$content);
```

Comment: Only using the `preg_replace_callback`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew could you show how

Comment: Like [here](http://ideone.com/7ySeh5).